# How to allow XML, JSON and CSV files to be uploaded when CSP is set in the webpage

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy, security

Currently, I have set the following CSP header in the HTML file of my webpage -

```
default-src 'none'; script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-RANDOM' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' ; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src * data:; media-src 'self' https://maps.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.google.com https://*.s3.amazonaws.com data:; form-action *; frame-src 'self' https://feed.mikle.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:; base-uri 'self'; connect-src *
```

There is a feature on our webpage that requires users to upload an XML file and another feature that requires JSON or a CSV file to work.

Is there a way to not restrict these files from being uploaded when the CSP is set? If so, how?

Comment: How are you uploading? Forms? Ajax? Are you uploading to your own domain or to another domain?

Comment: I use HTML forms to upload. Also, I'm uploading it to my domain only @root

Comment: Your `form-action *;` should do the trick - what error are you seeing in the console/network tab?

Comment: `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-rand' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' ". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.` This is the error that shows up in the console @root . I want to remove unsafe-inline from my policy. Will adding the nonce to my inline script make this work?

Comment: You should edit the question and provide all the information. If you're uploading forms, and you get blocked by `script-src`, then it's not the upload that is failing, something else is failing. Need a reproducible example, maybe even a HAR file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused and fixed as follows -

The button that takes XML file as input in the HTML form has an inline event handler, which the CSP Policy was blocking, thereby blocking the upload. I moved this inline event handler to an external function and called the function. This fixed the issue and CSP is no longer blocking the function.